# What STL function can I use to replace "while (var != nullptr)" loop?

Tags: c++, c++17, std

In book `C++ Core Guidelines Explained: Best Practices for Modern C++` there is a quote:

> There is a proverb in modern C++: “When you use explicit loops, you don’t know the algorithms of the STL.”

I am writing a program at the moment, which uses an explicit for loop, that changes an object pointed to by a variable in each iteration, until it points to `nullptr`.

```
    for(auto object = get_object(arg);object != nullptr;object = get_object_next(arg)) {
       if (condition) {
         vector_of_objects.push_back(object);
       }
    }
```

What STL function would be better suited for this than an explicit for loop?

Comment: If you want to use an STL algorithm, you probably need to wrap your functions in iterators that can be incremented to move to the next element.

Comment: The proverb underrates explicit loops. Ask your self what is most easily understood by someone reading your code. And consider the average competence of even professional developers.

Comment: The great thing about guidelines is they are just that, guidelines.  They can be ignored when they become burdensome.  You would have to write some boiler plate to get this to work with the standard algorithms, so don't.  The code is already clear and concise, no change is needed.

Comment: The algorithm you are emulating is `std::copy_if`.  As mentioned, all of these algorithms expect objects that model _iterators_ for iteration.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the `get_object()` / `get_object_next()` model of iteration is very bug-prone.  Your loop does not own its progression state, and any code anywhere could call `get_object(arg)` again, breaking the behavior of your loop.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Or `| std::views::filter(condition)`. If we could see the larger context, it might not even be necessary to materialize the  `vector_of_objects`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algorithms are ultimately built on iterators. Your loop is not. Therefore, there is no algorithm to fit it.

Now, if you're using this particular `get_object/get_object_next` interface frequently, it might be worthwhile to develop an iterator/range version of it. Presumably this would be some form of InputIterator/Range. The iterator would store the `arg` and a current object. `++` would replace the current object with `get_object_next(arg)`. It's a pretty simple interface, and the C++20 concepts system makes writing conforming iterators easier than ever (at the very least, it's easy to check to see if it is a valid `std::input_iterator`).

But if you only have a couple of places that use these loops, it's probably not worthwhile.

Of course, "couple of places" and "used frequently" are states that can change over time. So it may be worthwhile to provide a range/iterator interface if you think it might be frequently used.